# How to get field ref data in firebase in single call?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have below firestore collections.

```
-Converstions(collection)
 (document) {participants: {userid1: true, userid2: true}, messages: [subcollection]}
-Users(collection)
 (document)(userid1){userName: 'Test1', ...}
 (document)(userid2){userName: 'Test2', ...}
```

Now I need to query for conversations a users is in, I can do this with

```
firebase.firestore().collection('conversations')
.where(`participants.${uid}`, '==', true);
```

What this does is gets all conversation a users is participating in, I need to now get the user details from id for each document in those conversation. If we make another call to UserRef to get the user details it will make extra request for each conversation data. I wanted to know if there is easy way to get user details in single call to the firebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a user is added to a document, you could also add some display information about that user (either from the app or Cloud Functions).

There is no way to return data referenced elsewhere.  You either need to duplicate or make multiple fetches.

Comment: just did multiple fetches

Comment: In the Node SDK (getAll) and the REST API (batchGet), you can get multiple documents with a single call to Cloud Firestore.  I'm hoping that these may be added to other SDKs in the future.